# Want to remove a function from multiple files using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this 3 functions, looking exactly like this in multiple files, and using Notepad++, Find in Files/Replace in Files:

```
FirstLine
{
    //something here
}
SecondLine
{
    //something here
}
ThirthLine
{
    //something here
}
```

I want to remove the second function, the result should be like this:

```
FirstLine
{
    //something here
}
ThirthLine
{
    //something here
}
```

I have tried on regex101.com many times this is the last one i tried:

```
^.*(SecondLine).*\{.*\}.*$
```

just doesn't work, :(

Comment: You should be more clear about their structure otherwise they start asking lots of questions.

Comment: You should show your own attempts, otherwise we start complaining about "write my code" questions.

Comment: They look exactly like here...just some code inside of each of them..?!

Comment: This is the last one i tried: `^.*(SecondLine).*\{.*\}.*$`

Comment: So find `SecondLine[^{]*{[^}]*}` and replace with nothing. If this doesn't answer your question, it means my first comment is yet valid.

Comment: Really, writing regexes requires more information on the structure to match. I bet you will not be satisfied by regexes which assume that the code only consists of comments or even that they do not contain any `{}`. @revo is right, you know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve it by adding the info which currently is hidden in comments.

Comment: Please also desribe the result of your own attempts. In which way did they not satisfy you? And do so for more than one attempt. Otherwise "many times" reads so weird...

Comment: Curly brackets are not on the same line..that's why i said ..the code looks exactly like here...There's not result, nothing happens when i pres Replace in Files...0 occurrence...etc

Comment: Did you try the solution I suggested? https://regex101.com/r/QGIXNj/1

Comment: You are matching `SkinMesh` in your live demo while input string doesn't have string `SkinMesh`. What do you expect?

Comment: @revo, the regex might need a \r*\n* at the end, as in `SecondLine[^{]*{[^}]*}\r*\n*` to get OP's expected output (without emptylines in between the first and third method)

Comment: @Matt.G Let's see if it passes the tests from OP then we'll talk about details.

Comment: I'm trying ..i can see that is working there but here still doesn't work, maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The only culprit would be your string format. Double check.

Comment: Nothing changes, i have opened 10 files, directory is correctly set, using this code: `SecondLine[^{]*{[^}]*}\r*\n*` .

Comment: Is Regular Expression option selected  in `ctrl` + `h` window?

Comment: Geez..is killing me..:|

Comment: So, if i try to remove just one line,containing the string SeconLine..: `^.*(SecondLine).*$`, it's working fine, but with your code nothing happens'

Comment: Ok, fixed now..this works: `SecondLine[^\{]*\{[^\}]*\}\r*\n*` . Thank You for this,..:)

Comment: Weird that Notepad++ needs closing brace to be escaped! Never faced before.

Comment: I think you should answer your question now.

Comment: Trying, dunno how to answer to q anymore..:)

Comment: Just scroll to bottom of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up to use:

```
SecondLine[^\{]*\{[^\}]*\}\r*\n*
```

Notepad++ threw an *Invalid regular expression* error before I escaped braces. It seems closing braces should be escaped in a N++ regex to mean a literal `}` character.

Thank you all for the help!